# Coordinating reading lines from a file and using obtained data

Tags: java, file-io

Here is my code for reading lines from a CSV file :

```
private void input()throws IOException
    {
        //FILE READER FIELDS
        StringTokenizer st=null;
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
         String line=null;
         int count=0;
         while((line=b.readLine())!=null)
            {   

                count+=1;
                if(count==1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {   

                    String[]  arr=new String[19];
                    st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
                    int i=0;
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                    {
                    arr[i]=st.nextToken();
                    i++;
                    }
                    for(int j=2;j<arr.length;j++)
                    {
                        if(j==11)
                        {
                            calib_g=Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);

                        }
                        if(j==12)
                        {
                            coolant_temp=Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);

                        }
                        if(j==13)
                        {
                            engineRPM=Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
         }
```

As can be inferred from the code, the objective of the above `input` method is to read the file starting from the second line store the tokens obtained from the perused line in an array whose length is predetermined. Then, select elements from the array are used to update the static variables `calib_g` ,`engineRPM` and `coolant_temp`.

These variables are then used by the below method which updates COSM(previously pachube now xively) with  these values :

```
private void update(int feedid) throws PachubeException, IOException

{
Feed f = this.pachube.getFeed(feedid);

System.out.println("XML is :" + f.toXML());

input();
flag=false;

   System.out.println("updating ...");

     f.updateDatastream(8345, calib_g);
     f.updateDatastream(6274, coolant_temp);
     f.updateDatastream(1044, engineRPM);
       System.out.println("updated");
```

}

**Problem :** 
When the `input` method is called from within the `update` method, `while((line=b.readLine())!=null)` iterates over the entire loop and returns the values only from the last line.

**Objective :**
I want to upload data from a single line when the `upload` method calls the `input` method.Thus the flow of the program should be like this

- `update` method is called every 5 seconds using a `Timer` in the main method.
- The `update` method calls the `input` method.
- The compiler executes the `while` loop.While loop reads one line from
  the csv file.The line is tokenized and stored in the array.Selected
  elements of the array are used to update the `static` variables.
- The `update` method updates XIVELY with the aforementioned `static`
  variables.
- Go to step 1 .The `update` method is called again.
- The `input` method is subsequently called again . This time the next
  line of the csv file is used to update the `static` variables

Comment: The `input` method is looping over *all* the lines in the file, using that `while` loop that you've shown. It's really not clear what you mean... although it's distinctly odd design that `input` doesn't take any parameters or return anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet exactly. I need the `input` method to not loop over _all the lines_ in the file, it should first parse the 2nd line(I've already included the logic to skip the first) then halt counting lines when the `update` method calls it and resume counting when the variables have been updated.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using the `input` method to store new values in the `static` variables `coolant_temp`, `engineRPM` & `calib_g` which are obtained from the next line of the csv file.Is it simply odd or  a bad way to carry out what I am trying to do in the code?

Comment: But your comment that it "iterates the same line and files to consider the other lines" is simply not true - it will iterate over *all* lines in the file (but only one file). It's really unclear what you're trying to do, to be honest - but I'd suggest you make your `input` method take a filename as a parameter, and return the list of data elements it's read.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited the question.Hope its clearer now.

Comment: It's really not terribly clear - I think you should revisit your design, basically. Reading a single line each time is not a great idea - and I'd avoid static variables if you can. I would suggest reading the whole file in one go, and storing *that* in memory - it's much easier to iterate over a collection than it is to read to the specified point in the file each time. (You could keep the `BufferedReader` open the whole time, but that's pretty nasty too.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37221/discussion-between-jane-love-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: No, I don't have time I'm afraid. I think you need to take a step back, ignore the current design ideas you have, and consider what you really need to achieve.